# Loop for elements, but group them by attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes, unique

i want to loop elements, but group them by diferent attiribute values. And do some actions for the element groups whose has the same attribute values..

Example:

```
  $( "[hasdropdown]" ).each(function(){
         console.log($(this).attr('ui-menu-type'))
        $(this).hide() //or any other actions
    })

   Result :     
        (10) Category-Menu
        (5) Other-Menu
        (8) Sub-Menu
   // this is hiding them to many times
```

But i want this result :

```
Result :     
        (1) Category-Menu
        (1) Other-Menu
        (1) Sub-Menu
```

And change them once.

First Example also suitable for me, but it tooks long time to loop

**Is there a way to filter / unique them by same attributes and change them once?**

*I don't want solutions like another function or push attributes to array..*

**There must be a Jquery function for that !
(maybe filter() or unique() functions does it but i don't know how to handle them)**

Thank you very much!
p.s. sorry for my English

Comment: I don't see how the first code example gives the output you describe as it doesn't do anything except hide all the elements? Perhaps it would be better if you showed us the HTML you have and the output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] which clearly demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: I think i can't explain what i want, because of my English. I want to group [hasdropdown] elements whose has [ui-menu-type] attributes. And do action just one time for them. hide() is just for an example action. i have too many actions for them.

Comment: Your English seems fine to me. All we need to see is your HTML

Comment: Thank you. just not enough to explain what i want. My Html is very complicated. to help you to understand i want to create dropdown menus to [hasdropdown] attributes. but diffrent menu types for [ui-menu-type] attributes...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't paste your html, I'd try to show you how you can group you array elements based on whatever you want using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const arr = ['Category-Menu', 'Category-Menu', 'Category-Menu', 'Other-Menu', 'Other-Menu', 'Sub-menu', 'Sub-menu']; // original array of string

const result = arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
debugger;
 if(acc.indexOf(current) === -1) { // you should check if you element is already in result
  acc.push(current); // if not push it there
 }
 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! But i have solution like this. But i asked to learn : is there jquery function which gets elements by unique attributes.

Comment: I'm sure that jQuery have it. Post your sample html and provide you expectations and I'm pretty sure that we will help you very fast.

Answer (score 0):

its result is all i want and works for me:

```
var MenuType = $("[hasdropdown]").map(function(){return $(this).attr("ui-menu-type");}).get();

            const MenuTypes = MenuType.reduce((acc, current) => {
                if(acc.indexOf(current) === -1) {
                    acc.push(current);
                }
                return acc;
            }, []);


            MenuTypes.forEach(function(_E) {                    
                $( '[hasdropdown][ui-menu-type="'+_E+'"]' ).hide() //or any other actions
            });
```

But too many codes! I asked is jquery has a function to do each() function with less codes....

```
 $( "[hasdropdown]" ).GroupOrUniqueOrAnyOther(['ui-menu-type']).each(function(){
         console.log($(this).attr('ui-menu-type'))
        $(this).hide() //or any other actions
    })
```

Please give solutions like this...